# What is the cause of `ConsumerRemaining` error?

Tags: polkadot, multisig

When I transferred Approve_as_multi Tx from a child address in a multisig wallet at the time I went up to Polkadot Runtime v9420, I got a `Failed (ConsumerRemaining)` error.
This is the first time I have seen this error, what is the reason?

Comment: [This](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/dispatch/enum.DispatchError.html#variant.ConsumerRemaining) and [this](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_system/struct.AccountInfo.html#structfield.consumers) might help you dig down further.

Comment: What's the call you want to execute here?

Comment: any updates? I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the issue you're facing, but when I got this error it was because I didn't have enough free DOT to place the necessary reserve for the multisig call.

Make sure that you have enough liquid DOT to cover the depositBase PLUS the factor dependent deposit (i.e. a threshold of 5 requires 5x the depositFactor).

These deposits are subject to change, but right now the depositBase for a multisig is 20.088 DOT and the depositFactor is 0.32 DOT. So to approve a multisig call with a threshold of 5 would require a total of 20.088 + 5 x 0.32 = 21.688 DOT. You can always determine the current deposit requirements with a chain state query of the constants under the multisig pallet.

edit: don't forget, you always need the existential deposit in your account as free